# Understanding a for loop in an example

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, julia

**Please rather close or down this post try to teach and help me to understand**

As a newbie I have a very hard time to understand the following `for loop` code in `Julia`. I am sure this should be the same concept in other languages.

I would highly appreciate someone please **in details** explain to me why the following code for the `mylist[3]` would be `23`

```
mylist = [3, 2, 1]

count=3
for i in mylist
  mylist[i]=count
  count=count+10
end

mylist[3] = 23
```

**If you Know a good textbook/source/course to help me please let me know.**

Comment: mylist[3] is outside the boundaries of the mylist array. You cannot be getting mylist[3] = 23.

Comment: It's Julia code and not Python code, so `mylist[3]` is not outside the boundaries (1-based indexing).

Comment: @PrestonM it is true. please just copy and paste it into your Julia console or I Julia and enter it you will get 23.

Comment: Try to dry run your code, check the value of array in all the index. At index 1 the value is 3, at index 2 the value is 13 and at index 3 the value is 23.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas as an expert could you please help me with your explanation on it please.Thanks in advance for your time and kind help.

Comment: Please don't add the Python tag next time. It confused people into thinking it's Python code (somehow... even though it wasn't close to valid Python code...)

Comment: Sure, Sorry about that! My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just walk through the example. You're looping through the values of `mylist`, so the first `i` is 3. Therefore `mylist[i]=count` makes `mylist[3]=3`. `count=count+10` updates `count` to be `13`. The second time through `mylist` makes `mylist[2]=13` and then `count=23`. Then, since the first round made `mylist[3]=3`, we have `i=3` in the last round, which sets `mylist[i]=count` which is now `23`. Thus `mylist[3]=23`.

Use the REPL to walk through it yourself and it'll be more clear. Going step by step like this is a good way to understand code.

Answer (score 1):

**First loop:**
count=3 so mylist[3]=3 then count=13

**Second loop:**
count=13 so mylist[2]=13 then count=23

**Final loop:**
count=13 so mylist[3]=23 *Since third element in mylist is changed to 3 in first loop*.

Thus you get 23